# Android: string value is not getting in Shared Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have created a shared preference for a boolean value and for a string value. The boolean value is gotten in another activity. But for the string I am only getting default value.

### Home.class

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spe = prefs.edit();

    spe.putBoolean("flag", true); 
    spe.putString("user", "hello");
    spe.commit();
```

### welcome.class

```
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean flag= prefs.getBoolean("flag", false); 
    String user=prefs.getString("user","Nothing");  

      TextView tv = new TextView(this);
      tv.setText("Flag : "+flag+(" User : "+user);
```

For 'user', only 'Nothing' is displaying. Where should I correct my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(appName,0);
settings.getBoolean("flag", true);  
settings.getString("user", "hello");
```

And to put:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(appName,0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("flag",true);
editor.putString("user","hello");
editor.commit();
```

This is what I use in my application, and it shares booleans/ints/strings accrossed many many Classes

Note: appName doesn't have to be the app name, like in the official tutorial.